# Change HTML with angularJS syntax using a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS a bit and I want to do the following:

Create a table which has sortable columns and have an arrow image that describes the sorting direction.

What I tried to do is creating a directive called sort which takes the sorting column and changes the sortByColumn variable. This works fine. The only problem is when I try to change the class of the image.

At first I tried using the template to use like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
{
    ...
},
template: '<span class="image" ng-class="{is-visible: someVar == attrs.sort}"></span>'
```

This doesn't work because the attrs variable is not defined so the first question would be... is there a way to access the element's attributes inside the template?

If not, what I tried to do next is manually set the html inside the link:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
{
    element.html('<a href="#" onclick="return false;">' + element.html() + '<span class="sort-image" ng-class="{visible: true}"></span></a>');
}
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't evaluate the ng-class.

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: have a look at ng-grid from angular ui, it might be what you want, or you could see how they do it. http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: why not store the sort value on the scope, then you can access it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.directive('sort', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                sort: "@"
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                ...
            },
            template: '<a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span style="display:inline-block;" ng-transclude></span><span class="sort-image" ng-class="{visible: sort == (sortByColumn)}"></span></a>',
            transclude: true
        };
    });
```

I figured out the answer. I can just use the isolate scope "@" to pass the attribute value.